# Show that the curve has only one point

Tags: calculus

Show that the curve $y=8x+\left(\frac1{2x^2}\right)$ has only one turning point. Find the coordinates of the turning point and determine whether the turning point is a maximum point or a minimum point.

By diffrentation I get $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=8-4x^{-3}$ ...After that I'm lost! Please help! >.<

EDIT: Sorry i can't do the "/" symbol properly, can anyone teach me?

Comment: You would use `\frac` or `\dfrac` to make a fraction...

Comment: Let me try... $1/\dfrac2x^2$

Comment: \$\frac{A}{B}\$ = $\frac{A}{B}$

Comment: Note that you can review how your question was edited to see the changes that I made and thus how I made use of `\frac` and `\dfrac`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what the derivative tells you about the curve? Once you correctly derive, it tells you the slope of the curve at every point. At a turning point, the slope has to be zero, so you want to find where the derivative is equal to zero. Then you can try values around that point to see if it is a maximum or a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your derivative is incorrect...

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=8-\dfrac{1}{x^3}$

From there it is easy to find the zero...

EDIT: clarification of the derivative and finding the $0$

$y=f(x)=8x+\dfrac{1}{2x²}=8x+\dfrac{1}{2}x^{-2}$

$f'(x)=8+\dfrac{1}{2}(x^{-2})'=8+\dfrac{1}{2}\times(-2)(x^{-3})=8-x^{-3}$

Then, you are looking for $f'(x)=0$

$8-x^{-3}=0$ or $x^{-3}=8$, equivalent to $x^{-1}=2$ or simply $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$

This is the only solution.

Comment: And how would you use this information to determine that the function has only one turning point?

Comment: You look at all the possible zero of the equation... There is only one $x$ for which the expression is $0$

Comment: I apologize, Martigan..but how did you get that $-1\x^3$ I'm sorry my maths is not good enough... and in this case, how do we get the x points here? I'm confused in this stage

Comment: If you can't solve the equation $\displaystyle 8-\frac{1}{x^3}=0$ you are in a spot of bother... how did you differentiate the function without knowing that $\frac{1}{x^2}=x^{-2}$ and so $x^{-3}=\frac{1}{x^3}$?

Comment: Oh no! I notice it now! Sorry I'm such a careless person when comes to differentiation